# The argument type 'GlobalKey<NavigatorState>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type'GlobalKey<NavigatorState>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error:

```
The argument type 'GlobalKey<NavigatorState>?' can't be assigned to
the parameter type'GlobalKey<NavigatorState>'

.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
Map<BottomNavItem, GlobalKey<NavigatorState>> navigatorKeys
```

I do believe that I am passing the correct thing. But where does this question mark at the end shows up?

```
 Widget _buildOffStageNavigatorItem(
    BottomNavItem currentItem,
    bool isSelected,
  ) {
    return Offstage(
      offstage: !isSelected,
      child: TabNavigator(
        item: currentItem,
        navigatorKey: navigatorKeys[currentItem],
      ),
    );
  }

final Map<BottomNavItem, GlobalKey<NavigatorState>> navigatorKeys = {
    BottomNavItem.home: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
    BottomNavItem.scorecard: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
    BottomNavItem.rewards: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
    BottomNavItem.orders: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
  };
```

pls help

Answer (score 1):

Maps always return a nullable object. This is because there is no way to guarantee that the key you are accessing is there without limiting the map object.
If you know for sure the data is in there

```
navigatorKey: navigatorKeys[currentItem]!,
```

If you don't know for sure

```
var item = navigatorKeys[currentItem]
if (item == null) // Do something
return Offstage(
      offstage: !isSelected,
      child: TabNavigator(
        item: currentItem,
        navigatorKey: navigatorKeys[currentItem],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Null Safety issue as all others in Flutter 2.0. Best practice is really learn this approach and use ? and ! everywhere. In most cases it's solving by Alt+Shift+Enter in warning details window.

Answer (score 0):

this fixes it. `navigatorKey: navigatorKeys[currentItem]!,`

Basically I was assigning a nullable to non nullable